# Determining Overall Time Series Model Percent Improvement

Tags: python, time-series, loss-function

I have the true values as well as the predictions for both an older and a newer model ran on thousands of time series. My goal is to calculate the overall improvement of the new model over the old model. Below is an example of what my data looks like:

```
                 DATE  TRUE  OLD_PRED  NEW_PRED
TIME_SERIES                                    
0            21-10-01    10         5         9
0            21-10-02     0         1         0
1            21-10-01   500       600       550
1            21-10-02   501       600       550
```

My first approach was to use MAPE:

1. I quickly realized MAPE fails when the TRUE values are 0 so I simply dropped those rows and calculated the MAPE for both models across every time series.

   ```
                OLD_MAPE  NEW_MAPE
   TIME_SERIES                  
   0                50.0      10.0
   1                19.9       9.9
   ```
2. Then to get the percentage improvement for each time series, I would take the difference between the 2 values (old - new)

   ```
                PCT_IMPROVEMENT
   TIME_SERIES                  
   0                         40
   1                         10
   ```
3. Finally, I would take the mean over all time series to get the overall improvement

   ```
   (40 + 10)/2 = 25%
   ```

Now I'm considering using MAE:

1. Like MAPE, I would first calculate the MAE for both models

   ```
                OLD_MAE  NEW_MAE
   TIME_SERIES                  
   0                3.0      0.5
   1               99.5     49.5
   ```
2. Then I would figure out the percent improvement for each time series using the formula: (new - old)/old x 100 x -1. (times -1 because a lower loss score is better and would result in a positive percent improvement)

   ```
                PCT_IMPROVEMENT
   TIME_SERIES                     
   0                      83.33
   1                      50.25
   ```
3. Now since we are working with percents which is scale independent, I can take the mean across all the time series to end up with a single number which would be my overall percentage improvement.

   ```
   (83.33 + 50.25)/2 = 66.79%
   ```

Of course there will still be a few time series I have to drop from my calculation to avoid dividing by 0 in my actual data but there's far less with the MAE approach (3% vs almost 30% using MAPE.)

I'm wondering if this approach is sound or if there's a better way for coming up with an overall percentage improvement? My other concern is the overall percent improvement changes depending on if I use MAPE, MAE, MSE or RMSE making me wonder which metric would be the most correct?

Comment: Your approach with MAE seems solid enough. Do you need to report this improvement to the business owner? I usually compare the models performance in the development phase via grid search and cross-validation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Cross validation is great for this scenario because there usually isn't a single best model for all our time series so I should clarify the new predictions I'm comparing in my example are using this approach. I'm taking over an older project so I wasn't apart of the previous model's development phase. 

One thing I'm struggling with is that I noticed if I use MAPE to calculate the overall percentage improvement, it results in a very different value. Is one metric more correct than the other? (I will update the question to show the MAPE approach)

Comment: You might also want to compute something like  Wins compared to your previous model and losses compared to your previous model, where you could define a win if the new model is closer to target, and a loss otherwise. This might help you control that the model is not dropping the ball on a lot of datapoint, and also diagnose if there are any subgroups being "left behind"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calculating MAPE, you say:

> Then to get the percentage improvement for each time series, I would take the difference between the 2 values (old - new)

But you are actually describing how to calculate the difference in percentage points, not how to calculate the percent difference. Calculating the difference in percentage should be done the same way you did it for MAE. Here is an example of how to do it for one of the example data sets you provided, showing that the percent difference is in fact the same, regardless of whether you use MAE or MAPE.

```
import numpy as np

# setup your second timeseries
y_true = np.array([500, 501])
y_hat_old = np.array([600, 600])
y_hat_new = np.array([550, 550])

# calculate mape ------
# rounding to correct floating point precision issue
mape_old = np.round(np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_hat_old) / y_true)), 2)
print(mape_old)
# 0.2

mape_new = np.round(np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_hat_new) / y_true)), 2)
print(mape_new)
# 0.1

mape_percent_improvement = (mape_old - mape_new) / mape_old
print(mape_percent_improvement)
# 0.5

# calculate mae -----
# rounding to correct floating point precision issue
mae_old = np.mean(np.abs(y_true - y_hat_old))
print(mae_old)
# 99.5

mae_new = np.mean(np.abs(y_true - y_hat_new))
print(mae_new)
# 49.5

# again, rounding to correct floating point precision issue
mae_percent_improvement = np.round((mae_old - mae_new) / mae_old, 2)
print(mae_percent_improvement)
# 0.5

print(mape_percent_improvement == mae_percent_improvement)
# True
```